# Onchange event in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have two dropdown fields in jqgrid table indicating switch status as ON and Off.

If user selects 'ON' option in any one switch, other switch option should change to 'OFF' and vice versa. At a time user can enable only on switch. Both switches can be in 'OFF' state but can not be 'ON' state'. So, I need onchange event for the above as, if user select 'ON' option for Switch1 , Switch2 must change to OFF and if user select 'ON' option for Switch2 , Switch1 must change to OFF. Please share some idea.

Here is my code

```
grid_data = [{'Switch_1':'OFF', 'Switch_1':'OFF'},
         {'Switch_1':'ON', 'Switch_1':'OFF'},
         {'Switch_1':'OFF', 'Switch_1':'ON'},]
colNames:['Switch 1', 'Switch 2'],
colModel:[
     {name:'Switch_1',index:'Switch_1', width:55,editable:       true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{width:20, value:"0:OFF;1:ON"}}
     {name:'Switch_2',index:'Switch_2', width:55,editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{width:20, value:"0:OFF;1:ON"}}
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a jquery event listen to the dropdown change event. at which point you can do some logic to determine state.

```
$('#switch1').change(function(){
    if($('#switch1').val() == 'ON'){
       $('#switch2').val('OFF'); // you should put the value you set for off  
    }
});

$('#switch2').change(function(){
    if($('#switch2').val() == 'ON'){
       $('#switch1').val('OFF'); // you should put the value you set for off  
    }
});
```